# Limit Apache Camel RabbitMQ number of connections

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel

Is there any way to limit the number of connections that the Apache Camel RabbitMQ systems makes to the RabbitMQ server.  By default it seems to create a connection for each Camel consumer/producer.

Answer (score 0):

You can check options "threadPoolSize" and "channelPoolMaxSize" (http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html). Looks like the second one is what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  That is only for producers, and it only limits the channels, not the connection pool.

Comment: According to the source code for consumer mode, it used option "concurrentConsumers" option and number of concurrent consumers specified number of connections. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQConsumer.java#L86

Comment: For the producer mode, it looks like it opens only one connection per producer endpoint. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQProducer.java#L121